# C++ Openmp Nested Loops with Game Of Life and OpenGL

Tags: c++, openmp, race-condition

Im now a student in Berlin Germany. In this time I have to do a projekt for game of life and use OpenGL to display game and apply OpenMp for the high speed of the game. But I got stuck 2 months ago with data race. It is realy about 2 for loops, which I run to caculate new grid of game.

I try #pragma omp critical, reduction, ordered ... But the errors still throught by Vargind and I am so disappointed about this bug.

I declared 2 variable in the constructor to store grid of the game such as grid , and tempGrid for temprorary variable, and then copy all values of temGrid back into grid and redisplay the game. Pls hepl me if you have time, and if you do not understand me pls type something I will imediatly answer . Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
openmp is in the folder src

all of code : https://github.com/Chuvantinh/gameoflifegithub

constructor: in Gameoflife.cpp

```
    //! A public variable.
    /*!
      Grid: to store all element on openGL
    */
    bool** grid;

  //! A public variable.
    /*!
      Temproray variable: to store all element on openGL
      and then copy all into gird variable
    */
  bool** tempGrid;
GameOfLife::GameOfLife(const int w, const int h) : width(w), height(h)
{
    grid = new bool *[width];
    tempGrid = new bool *[width];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        grid[i] = new bool[height];
        tempGrid[i] = new bool[height];
    }

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
};
```

and the function interator with nested for loop

```
void GameOfLife::iterate()
{
// schedule(static) ordered
// #pragma omp for collapse(2)
 omp_set_nested(true); //Enables nesting. 
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) ordered
    for (size_t i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            // Edges
            if (i == 0 || i == (width - 1) || j == 0 || j == (height - 1))
            {
                #pragma omp ordered
                tempGrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                int neighbors = countNeighbors(i, j);
                if (grid[i][j] == true)
                {
                    if (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3)
                    {
                        // element survives
                        #pragma omp ordered
                        tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // element dies
                        #pragma omp ordered
                        tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (neighbors == 3)
                    {
                        // element is born
                        #pragma omp ordered
                        tempGrid[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // element empty
                        #pragma omp ordered
                        tempGrid[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    // move temgrid to grid 
    bool **t = grid;
    grid = tempGrid;
    tempGrid = t;
}
```

and the countNeighbours function

```
//! A function variable
    /*!
      Count the number of Neighbors without itself
      not count the edges of grid , see above code in the funtion iterator
    */
int GameOfLife::countNeighbors(int x, int y)
{
    int neighbors = 0;
    neighbors += grid[x - 1][y - 1];
    neighbors += grid[x][y - 1];

    neighbors += grid[x + 1][y - 1];
    neighbors += grid[x + 1][y];
    neighbors += grid[x + 1][y + 1];

    neighbors += grid[x][y + 1];
    neighbors += grid[x - 1][y + 1];
    neighbors += grid[x - 1][y];

    return neighbors;
}
```

UPDATE CODE:

in the main program: I created a object game and call the function in file gameoflife.cpp

```
/**
 * A main function only for openMP
 * work follow: getconfig
 * init object
 * show gird 
 * update grid
 * glutmainloop to wait funcion
 * finish
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    getConfigFile();
    game = new GameOfLife(game_width, game_height);
    game->randomInit();

    // game->printGrid();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

     
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Game of Life with OpenMP");
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

     glutMouseFunc(mouse);
     
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    update(0);
    glutMainLoop();
        
    return 0;
}
```

hier is function update():

```
/**
 * glutTimerFunc callbackfunction and afer time
 * glutPostRedisplay marks the current window as needing to be redisplayed.
 * @param int value 
 * @return void
*/
void update(int value) {
    //count = count + 1;
    //std::cout << " vong lap: " << count <<std::endl; 
    game->iterate();

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000 / FPS, update, 0);
}
```

The errors are :

```
==54225== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==54225== Copyright (C) 2007-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==54225== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==54225== Command: src/game
==54225== 
==54225== Warning: unimplemented fcntl command: 1033
==54225== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==54225== 
==54225== Thread #1 is the program's root thread
==54225== 
==54225== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==54225== 
==54225== Thread #2 was created
==54225==    at 0x4F20282: clone (clone.S:71)
==54225==    by 0x4DE32EB: create_thread (createthread.c:101)
==54225==    by 0x4DE4E0F: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:817)
==54225==    by 0x4842917: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==54225==    by 0x4DA74E5: gomp_team_start (team.c:836)
==54225==    by 0x4D9E59C: GOMP_parallel (parallel.c:169)
==54225==    by 0x10C1B7: GameOfLife::iterate() (GameOfLife.cpp:92)
==54225==    by 0x10AD7A: update(int) (main.cpp:167)
==54225==    by 0x10B680: main (main.cpp:284)
==54225== 
==54225== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==54225== 
==54225== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x57F10F8 by thread #1
==54225== Locks held: none
==54225==    at 0x4DA08A0: gomp_init_task (task.c:87)
==54225==    by 0x4DA7774: gomp_team_start (team.c:642)
==54225==    by 0x4D9E59C: GOMP_parallel (parallel.c:169)
==54225==    by 0x10C1B7: GameOfLife::iterate() (GameOfLife.cpp:92)
==54225==    by 0x10AD7A: update(int) (main.cpp:167)
==54225==    by 0x4886773: glutMainLoopEvent (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0)
==54225==    by 0x4886FF4: glutMainLoop (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0)
==54225==    by 0x10B685: main (main.cpp:285)
==54225== 
==54225== This conflicts with a previous read of size 8 by thread #2
==54225== Locks held: none
==54225==    at 0x4DA6EDE: gomp_finish_task (libgomp.h:838)
==54225==    by 0x4DA6EDE: gomp_thread_start (team.c:125)
==54225==    by 0x4842B1A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==54225==    by 0x4DE4608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==54225==    by 0x4F20292: clone (clone.S:95)
==54225==  Address 0x57f10f8 is 2,216 bytes inside a block of size 2,848 alloc'd
==54225==    at 0x483C893: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==54225==    by 0x4D990D8: gomp_malloc (alloc.c:38)
==54225==    by 0x4DA6F37: gomp_new_team (team.c:174)
==54225==    by 0x4D9E585: GOMP_parallel (parallel.c:169)
==54225==    by 0x10C1B7: GameOfLife::iterate() (GameOfLife.cpp:92)
==54225==    by 0x10AD7A: update(int) (main.cpp:167)
==54225==    by 0x10B680: main (main.cpp:284)
==54225==  Block was alloc'd by thread #1
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: the grid and tempGrid are local variables . how can I define tthat to  local because that is for display in openGL ?

Comment: Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x7EB3AF8 by thread #1
 GameOfLife::iterate() (GameOfLife.cpp:92)

Comment: Is it working if you disable openMP? From openMP point of view there is no data race: your read from `Grid` and write to `tempGrid[i][j]` (each thread uses different `i`). `#pragma omp` ordered can be removed and you can also collapse the 2 for loops. I think the problem may be with "//move temgrid to grid" section you probably wish to swap the values not only the address of an array of pointers. How do you call Iterate?

Comment: Yes, It is working both of two cases. I debuged with vargind and he told me this error "data race at #pragma omp parallel" . I remove "#pragma omp ordered" .
in main :  update(0);
in function update I call function interate() and it has a callback function for the calling again of interate().

Comment: ˇ"in main : update(0); in function update I call function interate() and it has a callback function for the calling again of interate()" please edit your post and add this part of your program...

Comment: If we ask you about a detail, please change your original post, it should include all the details, codes, error messages, problems, etc. Nobody wants to read a long discussion in comments .... We do not know e.g. which line is GameOfLife.cpp:92

Comment: should I show all of code on the github ?

Comment: https://github.com/Chuvantinh/gameoflifegithub

Comment: At first glance I don't see any data races here, you consistently update `tempGrid` and read from `grid`. That said, if efficiency is what you want an array of points is probably not ideal; in fact you should pretty much always store data like this in a single array (i.e. no ** but only * and then i*w+j to access elements). It is also not clear to me why you need nested omp, you don't use it, so you should probably not call that.

Comment: I am using ** for the store of array 1D, each element contains a another array . However, I can use vector, or array 2D in C++ for the store of matrix. But now it is so late to change it. I just want to fix this error at line "#pragma parallel omp".  I have removed "nested omp". But the erros are still there

Comment: I have found a post about openmp , they was trying with "prallel -> single -> ". I have tried that but the errors were still showed.

Comment: I find out a document about that. I followed also an instruction at >>9.5 Nested Loop Constructs<< but the error are still there . thanks
website is: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf